# Can PHP generators be cloned?

Tags: php, oop, clone, generator

In the PHP documentation it says that:

> This flexibility does come at a cost, however: generators are forward-only iterators, and cannot be rewound once iteration has started. This also means that the same generator can't be iterated over multiple times: the generator will need to either be rebuilt by calling the generator function again, **or cloned via the clone keyword**. *[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.comparison.php)*

However I tried writing a code that clones the generator object that I received from a method and I got an error specifying that a generator object cant be cloned:

```
class Course {
    private $students = array("avi" , "haim" , "maor" , "liran" , "yossi");

    function generateStudents() {
        foreach ($this->students as $student) {
            yield $student;
        }
    }
}

$ob = new Course();
$generator = $ob->generateStudents();

// Fatal error: Trying to clone an uncloneable object of class Generator
$generator2 = clone $generator;

?>
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 7):

[According to the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators#cloning_a_generator), generators cannot be cloned:

> Generators cannot be cloned.
>
> Support for cloning was included in the initial version, but removed in PHP 5.5 Beta 3 due to implementational difficulties, unclear semantics and no particularly convincing use cases.

It looks like the documentation reflects the initial version, and needs updating. There is a [documentation bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67011) raised to address this.

Also in the RFC, it refers to reasons why you might not want to reuse a generator:

> **Rewinding to some degree goes against the concept of generators, as they are mainly intended as one-time data sources that are not supposed to be iterated another time**. On the other hand, most generators probably *are* rewindable and it might make sense to allow it. One could argue though that rewinding a generator is really bad practice (especially if the generator is doing some expensive calculation). Allowing it to rewind would look like it is a cheap operation, just like with arrays.

Comment: IMO the redux-saga [`cloneableGenerator()`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Testing.md#branching-saga) and rationale make a strong and "convincing" example use case. Cloning generators lets you easily test branches of logic without repeating the initial steps.

Comment: Furthermore, the `Generator` class cannot be extended. Clone and extend support would allow authors to prevent cloning on a custom generator where it should be prohibited, or customize cloning semantics with `__clone()`.